# Escape result of FileLocator.resolve(url)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The method `FileLocator.resolve(url)` can be used to translate an address `bundleentry://something/somewhere/x.txt` to a proper file URL for `/mnt/foo/somewhere/x.txt`.

However, which is also documented at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=145096, the URL is not escaped. As an example, if the Eclipse installation containing the referenced bundle is in a directory containing a space, the URL returned by `FileLocator.resolve` still contains the space and calling `url.toURI()` fails because of that.

- How can I manually escape *all* necessary characters in the URL?
- How can I get a `File` object based on a path relative to the current
  bundle?

As reference, here is the code that fails when trying to find the directory `dir` inside my plugin's `.jar` file if that file is in a directory containing a space:

```java
    final IPath pathOfExampleProject = new Path("dir");
    final Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(AproveIDs.PLUGIN_ID);
    final URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, pathOfExampleProject, null);
    final URL url2 = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
    url2.toURI(); // Illegal character in path at index [...]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found this code:

http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/editor/tools/plugins/com.google.dart.tools.core/src/com/google/dart/tools/core/internal/model/BundledSystemLibrary.java?r=2057

The relevant lines indeed help:

```
// We need to use the 3-arg constructor of URI in order to properly escape file system chars.
URI resolvedUri = new URI(resolvedUrl.getProtocol(), resolvedUrl.getPath(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two additional notes:

- FileLocator.resolve indeed resolves an URL, but it does not necessarily return a file:/ URL. In the default case where your bundle is packed (in a .jar), you should use FileLocator.toFileURL, which automatically extracts the resource to a cache if needed.
- since Eclipse 4.x now includes EMF Common API by default, you can escape the URL more simply with EMF's URI API as follows:

`URI resolvedUri = URI.createFileURI(resolved.getPath());`

To get the file name, call `resolvedUri.toFileString();`

Answer (score 0):

From [Vogella Blog:](http://blog.vogella.com/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/)

```
URL url;
try {
    url = new 
    URL("platform:/plugin/de.vogella.rcp.plugin.filereader/files/test.txt");
    InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}

in.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To get the URL, Following can be used:

```
Bundle thisBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
URL fileURL = thisBundle.getEntry("<relative_file_path_from_project_root");
```

Also, one can choose the type of Stream/Reader to read image/text.