# How to access the member files and folders of a plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have a plug-in that is exported to an RCP product. In the plug-in, there is a folder that has some files. How can I access the plug-in files under a certain folder in Eclipse programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator` class to access files in a plugin.

```java
Bundle bundle = ... bundle containing the files

IPath path = new Path("relative path in plug-in of the file");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);

URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

The `url` returned by the `FileLocator.find` method uses an Eclipse specific scheme and can only be used with certain Eclipse APIs.

The `FileLocator.toFileURL` call converts the URL to a normal `file` URL, it may be necessary to unpack the plug-in jar to a temporary location in order to do this.

You can get the `Bundle` using

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

which gets the bundle containing the current class or

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

to access a bundle by plug-in id.

Comment: platform:/plugin what about this solution FileLocator results in finding the file in File System folder not in the plugin.

Comment: man It worked! I used new File (fileUrl.toURI()) then It became file.

Comment: How can I generate a File from this. fileUrl.toURI failed due to a eclipse bug #145096 It fails when there is a space in folder name.

Comment: There is some discussion of this in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14676966/2670892). I haven't run in to this problem myself.

Comment: I used    URIUtil.toURI(fileUrl)  .